# AttributeError: 'InputLayer' object has no attribute 'inbound_nodes'

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, coreml, coremltools

I've got the following error: https://pastebin.com/X7146Ury
when running this [script](https://github.com/hollance/CoreML-Custom-Layers/blob/master/convert_lambda.py).

```
AttributeError: 'InputLayer' object has no attribute 'inbound_nodes'
```

Comment: Error seems to come during CoreML conversion. Why not tagged as `coreml`, too??

Comment: @desertnaut added

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In the latest version of Keras this was renamed to `_inbound_nodes` (note the added underscore). The version of coremltools you're using does not appear to be compatible with that Keras version yet.

However, the latest version on GitHub *does* appear to use the new `_inbound_nodes` name. I suggest you install that, using:

```
pip install -U git+https://github.com/apple/coremltools.git
```

Answer (score 0):

I was trying to write a custom layer, the problem was the class which I was subclassing, instead of `from tensorflow.keras.layers import Layer`, I used

```
from Keras import layers
class layerName(layers.Layer):
    #impelementation
```

and it worked.